# X11. How to know the full size of a window (with the size of its decorations)

Tags: unix, x11

I would like to retrieve the complete size of any windows in X11 in order to automatically resize it.

So far I have used wmctrl but the size seems to be incomplete.
for instance

```
>$ wmctrl -lG
0x00e0000f -1 0    0    1920 1200 tclogin1 KDE Desktop
0x010000ee -1 0    1160 1920 40   tclogin1 kicker
0x01200008  0 4    28   1920 1127 tclogin1 ...p7zip_9.13/bin - Shell No. 8 - Konsole
```

The Kicker height is 40 and the screen resolution is 1920x1200 so If I wanted to resize my Konsole to take all the screen but the kicker its size should be 1920x1160 (1200-40).

But when I do that, the Konsole overlaps the kicker size. 
So I assume that its means that the windows decorations might not be taken into account here.

How can I know the size of the decorations that I would have to add to the windows size given by wmctrl ?

Thanks

Comment: I asked the wrong question. How can I know the size of the decorations for a X11 window ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat allborders.sh 
# assumptions:  
#   windows ids are at least 5 digits long
#   we dont need to bother with windows that have no name
#   "first argument" from the pipe is east (could be west)
#   

WINDOW_IDS=`xwininfo -int -root -tree   |\
    grep '[0-9]*\ (has no name)' -v     |\
    grep -Eo '[0-9]{5,}'`

for win in $WINDOW_IDS;
do 
    xprop -id $win |\
        grep -Ee '^(_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS|WM_CLASS)' |\
        sed 's/.*=\ //' |\
        sed -e :a -e '/$/N;s/\n/ /;ta' |\
        grep  ^[0-9]    |\
    while read line;
    do
        set -- $line
        E=`echo $1|sed 's/,$//'`
        W=`echo $2|sed 's/,$//'`
        N=`echo $3|sed 's/,$//'`
        S=`echo $4|sed 's/,$//'`
        NAME=`echo $5|sed 's/,$//'`
        CLASS=`echo $6|sed 's/,$//'`
        echo -e "$CLASS $NAME $N $E $S $W"
    done
done
$ ./allborders.sh 
"URxvt" "urxvt" 1 1 1 1
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"Firefox" "Navigator" 18 1 3 1
"Gmpc" "gmpc" 18 1 3 1
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "one" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "one" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"XTerm" "aterm" 0 0 0 0
"FbPager" "fbpager" 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: How do you get the decorations size because this is what I want

Comment: I think that xwininfo gives the info without the decorations. Let's take an example: I want to have firefox taking all the screen but not overlapping the kicker as I use KDE. kicker is x=0, y=1160, w=1920, h=40. So if the resolution is 1920x1200, firefox coordinates and dims should be x=0, y=0, w=1920 and h=1160. If I do that firefox overlaps the kicker and goes a little bit out of screen on the right. The correct size is w=1914 and h=1128 (done using wmctrl). So the decorations are w=6 and h=32. How Can I get this information for every window ? Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems more reasonable. I will look at the script flag it as the right answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: Tested and it is working. I've got the impression that in some cases there are some pixels left (1 or 2 on some specific window types) but it is fine for what I want to do. Thanks a lot